# Google Search Console | SEO

Tags: angular, seo, google-search, google-search-console

Опубликовал сайт пару дней назад. Подтвердил права тегом и создал апишку для sipemap. Апи для sitemap работает должным образом. Гугл принял полученный sitemap и показал что успешно обработал 13 адресов.
Теперь вопрос. В google search console все пусто.

Обработка карты сайта. Сегодня это действия я повторил, дата сегодняшняя, хотя отправлял еще пару дней назад первый раз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все остальные данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ведите, все пусто. site map еще не обработал? хотя показывает, что все успешно. Есть нюанс, у меня сайт написан на Angular 8. Знаю, что для индексации это плохо, но сами страницы он то должен проиндексировать? или все таки дело в SPA движке? Спасибо.